# Basic SwiftUI Animation using `withAnimation` block over a Bool value

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am having a basic SwiftUI view setup. When I tap the `Show` button, I expect the overlay to appear with a 2-second animation. Similarly, when I tap the `close` button on the overlay view, I anticipate the overlay to dismiss with a 2-second animation.

Xcode: 14.3.1
iOS Target: 16.4

```
struct Playground: View {
    
    @State private var showDetailView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show") {
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0)) {
                    showDetailView = true
                }
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay {
            if showDetailView {
                show()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func show() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Close") {
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0)) {
                    showDetailView = false
                }
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .offset(y: 100)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(.black)
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I run the code on a simulator(iOS 16.4), the first time I tap the `Show` button, the overlay animates in correctly. Additionally, when I tap the `close` button, the overlay animates out as expected. However, the problem arises when I tap the `Show` button for the second time. The animation seems to vanish, and instead of animating in, the overlay instantly appears after a 2-second delay. Strangely, the "close" button continues to animate the fade-out correctly.

Comment: Does this also happen when you launch the app in the Simulator or device? What I'm seeing on my machine (same versions) is that this is only breaking in Xcode previews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one is Working.

**Xcode:** 14.3 **iOS Target:** 16.4

```
@State private var showDetailView: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Show") {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2.0)){
                showDetailView = true
            }
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .overlay {
        if showDetailView {
            show()
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
func show() -> some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Close") {
            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0)) {
                showDetailView = false
            }
        }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .offset(y: 100)
    }
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    .background(.black)
}
```